# jquery datatable - "jqueryui modal" is creating duplicate dialog html in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datatables

I am trying to implement jQuery datatable - jQuery UI modal functionality in my ASP.NET application. (as below)

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/jqueryui-modal.html

The issue I am seeing is, the dialog is creating duplicate html entry in the page.

I can see the issue in the datatable website also (click on the plus sign in each row to launch the dialog. Duplicate html entry will be created.)

[image]

Any suggestion / recommendation to avoid duplicate entry will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time you click to open one it creates a new modal whereas when you close it, it simply changes it's display property to none, leaving it in the DOM.

You need to remove the modal from the DOM after/when it's closed. Fortunately jQuery UI has a pretty robust API and that modal (dialog) has events you can listen for.

I don't know what your particular selectors are for your modal, so you'd need to adjust the following but basically you can listen for the close event of the dialog and remove it on close.

```
$(".selector").dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try that.

Comment: You're welcome. and again you may need to adjust the selectors to suit your code.  But the principal remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I really wanted to add something here to help many others. After trying all the work-arounds for this I learned something really important. If you load a complete DOM into the dialog window another instance is created and you will struggle big time. In my case, I am loading a partial view in MVC and sure enough it shows a complete DOM from  on. I've seen many posts about trying to destroy, remove, and even manually removing the duplicates with loops. These are not really answers but a band-aid for another problem. Also, when loading data in the dialog it is possible when doing an ajax call be careful you are not double loading scripts in the process. If you need to call $('.selector').dialog().dialog() then something is wrong the first instance has a conflict.

My solution which worked while none of the others did.
1) I modified my partial view placing a  to contain only the inner html I needed.
2) Fetching the data returns an entire DOM so I I used find() to limit what was returned in the dialog.
3) When closing the dialog use the dialog('close') method which is all that is required even according to the documentation.

If you have a refresh issue be careful constructing the dialog I opted to steer clear of the doc ready construct as it can sometimes cause conflicts. The dialog can be constructed when used.

Be careful what data is really being returned odd behavior will result.

And now it functions as expected as below I really hope this will save some hours of endless nothing for someone :) it worked for me.

```
var editOptDialog = YourOptions

Open:
         $("#dialog-edit").dialog(editOptDialog);
         $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
         $.get($(element).attr('url'), function (data) {
             $("#dialog-edit").dialog().html($(data).find('#content-modal'));
         });
Close:
         $("#dialog-edit").dialog().dialog("instance").close();
```